# How do I set the timeout of the Thrift client on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, thrift

When I send a request to the Thrift server, I want set a timeout. What should I do?

```
// 创建连接和客户端
const options = {
  connect_timeout: 1000,
  timeout: 1000,
  transport: thrift.TBufferedTransport,
  protocol: thrift.TBinaryProtocol
};
```